# Echo drop down list in a PHP Form

Tags: php, html, forms, html.dropdownlistfor

I have been trying to display this drop down list in my PHP form but when I open it on the browser it gives me a blank page, I have tried opening the page by removing the list and it runs properly. I also tried running the drop down list code independently and it runs properly. I have checked the  and  codes too but to no avail. The form is in a function as shown below:

```
            function showForm() {

               include("library/daloradius.conf.php");

                    echo "  <b>
                   ".$configValues['CONFIG_SIGNUP_MSG_TITLE']."
                              </b>

                            <br/><br/>
                            <form name='signup' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>

                            <table>
                                    <tr><td><b>First name:</b></td><td> <input type='text' value='Conference' name='firstname' /> </td></tr>

                                    <tr><td><b>Number:</b></td><td> <input type='text' value='' name='number' /> </td></tr>

                                    <tr><td><b>Bundle Type</b></td><td>   
                                    <select name = "Bundle" size = "1"> <option value ="10MB">10MB</option><option value     ="25MB">25MB</option><option value ="50MB">50MB</option></select></td></tr>

                                    <tr><td><b>Enter the verification code in the image:</b> <img src='include/common/php-captcha.php'></td>
                                    <td><input name='formKey' type='text' id='formKey' /></td></tr>
                           </table>
            <br/><br/>

                                    <tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register' /> </td></tr>
            <br/><br/>
                            </form>
                            ";
            }


            switch ($status) {
                    case "firstload":
```

Comment: `<select name = "Bundle" size = "1">`, you should use simple quotes because it's "breaking" your string. Same wherever you use double quotes.
(In fact I would avoid using `echo` here but that's not the question.)

Comment: might be in your `daloradius.conf.php` aswell, what's the content of that file?

Comment: @caCtus thanks a TON mate. It works, still used to the common HTML syntax. Again though, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You are jumbling with single and double quotes.

```
<select name = "Bundle" size = "1"> <option value ="10MB">10MB</option><option value     ="25MB">25MB</option><option value ="50MB">50MB</option></select></td></tr>
```

Change it to:

```
<select name = 'Bundle' size = '1'> <option value ='10MB'>10MB</option><option value     ='25MB'>25MB</option><option value ='50MB'>50MB</option></select></td></tr>
```

Please check for whole code the same way.